# How to attach background to Render Layers node?

Tags: render-layers

I have created a second Render Layers node to add the background of the scene but first I can get it attached to the second Render Layers node:
[image: First image]

And when I add background to attach it to the second Render Layers, I get it attached to the object instead of to the background:
[image: Second Image]

Could somebody tell me what steps I am missing? Please take into account that I am an absolute beginner.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to do? I can probably help but I just don't know what the problem is

Comment: You can also input your background image with an image node instead of creating a new renderlayer. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/input/image.html#image-node

Comment: Dear Cos Dim: Sorry for taking so long in answering. As you can see in the viewer of the file and image attached, the flames should be on the Render Layer created for the background. Instead, it's on the gauge itself. How can I place it on the background?